# Function that returns colored circle in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to define a function that returns a circle with a given radius, center and filled color. My function now only returns a circle with a given radius and center but I do not know how to implement a variable that fills the circle with any given color. Here is the function code for the circle as is:

```
function h = circle(x,y,r)
hold on
th = 0:pi/100:2*pi;
xunit = r * cos(th) + x;
yunit = r * sin(th) + y;
h=plot(xunit,yunit)
hold off
```

I think I need to change h=plot... to h=fill(xunit,yunit,'color') but I do not understand how. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do what you wrote. E.g.

```
h = fill(xunit, yunit, 'red');
```

It handles your circle as a polygon and fills it with red.

Comment: Yes but I want to be able to call the function and assign any arbitrary color without having to change in the code. How can I do that?

Comment: Then use `h = fill(xunit, yunit, r, color)` and your function declaration should look like `function h = circle(xunit, yunit, r, color)`, where color is a string. You can call this function like
`myCirc = circle(1,0, 2, 'blue');`.